# C# Linq - Add Null Values and Week Numbers to a List when they are missing

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, distinct-values

I have successfully managed to use Group a list by Category and WeekNumber no problem.
The problem I am facing is how to add in a 0 and fill in missing WeekNumber values.
If I just had 'Cars' then it would be nice and easy, but I can't seem to be able to use Distinct() correctly to iterate through each category.

**Current List:**

[image: Current List]

**Expected Result:**

[image: Expected Result]

If the list just had cars, then I know I could do the following to get a full years worth.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 52; ++i)
{
   if (vehicleSales.Count(x => x.x == i) == 0)
   {
      vehicleSales.Add(new WeeklySalesBreakdown { WeekNumber = i, Value = 0, Category = "Cars" });
   }
}
```

Help and advice appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need the data in a list and not in an object that you can navigate later like:
`salesBreakdownByCategory["Cars"][2]  //get salesBreakdown for Cars, then get week 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly changed your code, now you can do add zero valued records for all the categories that exist on your original list for 1 whole year (52 weeks):

```
var categories = vehicleSales.Select(v => v.Category).Distinct().ToList();
foreach(var category in categories)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 52; ++i)
    {
        if (!vehicleSales.Any(x => x.Category == category && x.WeekNumber == i))
        {
            vehicleSales.Add(new WeeklySalesBreakdown { WeekNumber = i, Value = 0, Category = category });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code can get slow, as you iterate over all entries with '.Count(x => x.x == i)') 52 times (when you have millions of entries this snowballs, with just a few entries you will not notice much).

What you can do is to store the data in a Dictionary:

```cs
salesBreakdownByCategory = new Dictionary<String, int[]>();
```

then you once go over all your entries once:

```cs
foreach(var breakdown in vehicleSales)
{
    int[] values;
    if(!salesBreakdownByCategory.TryGetValue(vehicleSales.Category, out values))
    {
        values = new int[52]; // every entry in the array is by default 0 
        salesBreakdownByCategory[vehicleSales.Category] = values;
    }
    values[vehicleSales.WeekNumber-1] = vehicleSales.Value;
}
```

that way you have all the data stored in the Array, but if you want to have a list you have to run over your data structure once again:

```cs
var result = salesBreakdownByCategory.SelectMany(x=>x.Select( (value,index) => new WeeklySalesBreakdown { WeekNumber = index+1, Value = value, Category = x.Key}));
```

When you want to avoid additional memory allocations and add the data to your existing list, instead of storing the value in an array of int as in the example above, you can use an array of bool instead and set the value to true for every entry that you find. Then you just need to iterate over the dictionary again and add an entry to your original list whenever the bool was not set to true

Comment: Thanks for this @CitrusO2 - Although marked other answer as that sorted me for now, I will definitely look at refactoring my code to this.